# I can't figure out what is missing in my PHP-based upload program

Tags: php, file-upload, move-uploaded-file

I've successfully uploaded the mp3 file to the server (local), and I'm trying to move the file to the destination folder which is located in the `/opt/lampp/htdocs` folder and folder name is **songs**. But the file is not being moved to the folder.

This is my html code for uploading file (I'm trying to move an mp3 file):

```
<form method="post" action="../scripts/saveAudio.php" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="song"><br></br>
    <div class="uploadbtn" align="center"><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"></div>
</form>
```

And this is php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
if (($_FILES['song']['type'] == "audio/mpeg"))
{
    $tempName = $_FILES['song']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $desPath = "../songs/" . $_FILES['song']['name'];
    
    if ($_FILES['song']['error'] > 0)
    {
        header('Location: ../src/uploadSongs.html');
        exit();
    }
    
    if (file_exists("../songs/" . $_FILES['song']['name']))
        {
            echo $_FILES['file']['name'] . " already exists. ";
        }
    if(!move_uploaded_file($tempName, $desPath))
        {
            echo "File can't be uploaded";
        }
}

else
{
    echo "Please Upload MP3 files only";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting `File can't be uploaded` or what is current behavior? Usage of `[$key]` seems incorrect

Comment: `$_FILES['song']['tmp_name'][$key]` What is `$key`? Did you print out `$tempName` and `$desPath` to make sure they are correct?

Comment: I think you need to revisit your logic a bit. Right now, if the file already exists, you'll echo that but then you go on and move it, overwriting the existing one anyway?

Comment: Please change the title to the reasonable topic.

Comment: @user3783243 yes I am getting File can't be uploaded

Comment: @brombeer I copied it from the documentation of this FILES function. And it is from the official site of php.

Comment: @brombeer yes both $tempName and $desPath are correct in the print

Comment: What is the output of `$_FILES`? From what you've posted I cant see how this would be correct with the `$key`.

Answer (score -1):

Before you apply the following code, make sure that you have increasesed "upload_max_filesize" in php.ini. If you don't change this value, you will get errors.

The location of php.ini is in "/etc/php/7.X/apache2/php.ini". Just replace 7.X with your php version.

The structure of my project is the following:

```
- fileUpload.php // upload file and store it in folder songs
- songs          // folder to store uploaded files
```

And the code (it can be used for multiple files with some modifications):

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

    $numberOfFiles = sizeof($_FILES["song"]["name"]);
    echo "<br>Number of selected files: ".$numberOfFiles.'<br>';

    $counter = 0; // get the first file from a list of files
    $tempName = $_FILES['song']['tmp_name'][$counter];
    $desPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/songs/" . $_FILES['song']['name'][$counter];



    if (file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/songs/" . $_FILES['song']['name'][$counter]))
    {
        echo $_FILES['file']['name'] . " already exists. ";
    }
    if(!move_uploaded_file($tempName, $desPath))
    {
        echo "File can't be uploaded";
    }

}

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="song[]" accept="audio/mpeg3"><br></br>
    <div class="uploadbtn" align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"></div>
</form>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: What are you advising the user changes and why? This code is open to XSS injections.

Comment: This code is just a test example, of how to upload files. In a real-world project the developer should avoid xss injections, alongside with other attacks.